# 404 Not Found in API testing

Tags: laravel, postman

I did my API backend in Laravel

I tested `Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');`
using `http://localhost/cloudengine-sandbox/cloudsandboxbackend/public/api/register`

and it work fine.
I have issues when I wanted to test the shortcodes.

**api.php**

```php
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
Route::get('profile', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');

Route::get('/shortcodes', 'ShortcodeController@index')
    ->name('shortcodes.index');

Route::post('/shortcodes', 'ShortcodeController@store')
    ->name('shortcodes.store');

Route::get('/shortcodes/{shortcode}', 'ShortcodeController@show')
    ->name('shortcodes.show');

Route::put('/shortcodes/{shortcode}', 'ShortcodeController@update')
    ->name('shortcodes.update');

Route::delete('/shortcodes/{shortcode}', 'ShortcodeController@destroy')
    ->name('shortcodes.destroy');
```

What do I type in the POSTMAN to test each of the shortcodes.

I typed `http://localhost/cloudengine-sandbox/cloudsandboxbackend/public/api/shortcodes/show`

I expected OK, but gave 404 Not found

Comment: Are you passing the right parameters in your get request in postman? as in Key : shortcode, value : show?

Comment: post  your controller's show method

Comment: Controller show method:   '    public function show(Shortcode $shortcode)
    {
        return $shortcode;
    }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names on the Routes are just shortcuts but when accessing them as urls, you still need to use the entire url as defined.

In your example, the url must be:

`http://localhost/cloudengine-sandbox/cloudsandboxbackend/public/api/shortcodes/{shortcode}`

Replace `{shortcode}` with a valid id of a shortcode in your database.

Make sure you bind `shortcode` to your model on the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: How do I consume it on Angular 7

Answer (score 1):

if you are writing test cases for your application then

Set your app url in your `.env` .

```
APP_URL=http://web.local  //Any url that you  are using.
```

Because laravel creates a url using `APP_URL` from the `.env`.

if you are testing using POSTMAN

Also make sure you pass the header `ACCEPT=application/json` in the POSTMAN.